# C getopt does not read all the parameters

Tags: c, linux, getopt

I have an assignment in C that requires options to be read in for different forms of a program. Before I start on that, though, I want to make sure that the `getopt` portion is working fine. However, the program keeps dropping the last parameter and I don't know why. Whenever I enter the last char, the program goes to the default value that kills the program. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int sFlag = 0;
    int lFlag = 0;
    int dFlag = 0;
    int rFlag = 0;
    int c;
    opterr = 0;

    while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "slr:")) != -1)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
            case 's':
                sFlag = 1;
                break;
            case 'l':
                lFlag = 1;
                break;
            case 'r':
                rFlag = 1;
                break;
            default:
                printf("unknown parameter introduced");
                exit(-1);
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("s = %i, l = %i, d = %i, r = %i", sFlag, lFlag, dFlag, rFlag);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: How are you calling your program?

Comment: gcc project.c -o project

Comment: No no, I meant how are you *invoking* or *running* the compiled program? I don't care how you *compile* the program, I assume you know how to do that.

Comment: I run it with "./project -slr"

Comment: The `-r` option expects a mandatory argument.

Comment: Ok, thank you. My teacher failed to explain that to met.

Comment: That's what [manuals are for](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

The colon symbol after `r` in `"slr:"` tells `getopt()` to wait for a mandatory argument which follows `-r`.

Examples:

1. `getopt(argc, argv, "slr:")` can parse `./project -s -l -r r_arg` (or `./project -r r_arg -s` etc.)
2. `getopt(argc, argv, "s:lr:")` can parse `./project -s s_arg -l -r r_arg`
3. `getopt(argc, argv, "s:lr:")` can also parse `./project -s -l -r r_arg` with no *error*, but the program works differently from user's expectation.  This is because `getopt()` expects `-s` to be followed by its argument, however it looks like, so the next argument `-l` is consumed and will not hit your `switch(c)`.